# Inserting Images anywhere on the page

Tags: graphics

So, every time, I try to insert an image, it puts the image at the top of that page or at the top of the next page. However, what if I wanted to insert it where I want it to insert? For example, try the following:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\title{Test Document, with default template}
\author{Ahaan S. Rungta}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagebreak
Hello, in this lecture, we will prove that $ 2 + 2 = 4 $. So, we use barycentric coordinates, as shown this figure: 
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{iphoo_logo}
    \caption{I don't even need this.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Notice what happens; the figure gets inserted at the top of the page. How can I make it appear right where I tell it to appear? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A figure can get bumped to the next page if the figure is too big to fit on the current page.  Is this the case?  You can modify the height (for example) of the image by using `\includegraphics[height=<integer>mm]{image_name}`. I've arbitrarily used mm as my dimension but other options exist.

Comment: No. That's not the problem. I have tried scaling my figure down to a minute size and the only difference is it doesn't get bumped to the next page but it goes to the top of *that* page. 

And my concern is something else, anyway. My concern is about the figure going all the way up to the top rather than stay mid-way in the page, where I want it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625) If you don't want an image to float, *don't* put it in a `figure` environment.  See Herbert's answer to the linked question (not the accepted answer) for an example like this.

Comment: Thanks! I did use the Search Function to now avail, but I guess I didn't try hard enough. You should post that as an answer, so that I can accept it. ;)

Comment: @AhaanRungta Generally with duplicates we will just close the question as a duplicate rather than add an identical answer to this question.